# Log4j2 - Java stack trace in one single event

Tags: java, exception, log4j2

We are using Log4j 2 version 2.7* and using Log4j2.properties file not an XML.

We are also using Kibana for log monitoring. But whenever there's an exception, the java stack trace error is being documented as single event per line.

I want the whole java stack trace to be in one document in Kibana elastic search.

I have tried appender.console.layout.stacktraceAsString=true.  It did not work.

Is there any way we could transform the java stack trace to be documented as one document rather than printing each stack trace line as separate document. IT gets really ugly in kibana when there's an exception.